# Meaning of a struct with embedded anonymous interface?

Tags: go

[`sort`](https://golang.org/src/sort/sort.go) package:

```
type Interface interface {
    Len() int
    Less(i, j int) bool
    Swap(i, j int)
}

...

type reverse struct {
    Interface
}
```

What is the meaning of anonymous interface `Interface` in struct `reverse`?

Comment: For searchers, there is a much simpler explanation here: [A Closer Look at Golang From an Architect’s Perspective](http://thenewstack.io/a-closer-look-at-golang-from-an-architects-perspective/).  Don't let the title of the article scare you off. :)

Comment: AIUI, that article ("A Closer Look...") doesn't actually talk about what it means to embed anonymous interfaces into a struct, it just talks about interfaces in general.

Comment: Embedding interfaces in a struct allow for partially "overriding" methods from the embedded interfaces. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70300399/839733) for details and an example other than sorting.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In this way reverse implements the `sort.Interface` and we can override a specific method
without having to define all the others

```
type reverse struct {
        // This embedded Interface permits Reverse to use the methods of
        // another Interface implementation.
        Interface
}
```

Notice how here it swaps `(j,i)` instead of `(i,j)` and also this is the only method declared for the struct `reverse` even if `reverse` implement `sort.Interface`

```
// Less returns the opposite of the embedded implementation's Less method.
func (r reverse) Less(i, j int) bool {
        return r.Interface.Less(j, i)
}
```

Whatever struct is passed inside this method we convert it to a new `reverse` struct.

```
// Reverse returns the reverse order for data.
func Reverse(data Interface) Interface {
        return &reverse{data}
}
```

The real value comes if you think what would you have to do if this approach was not possible.

1. Add another `Reverse` method to the `sort.Interface` ?
2. Create another ReverseInterface ?
3. ... ?

Any of this change would require many many more lines of code across thousands of packages that want to use the standard reverse functionality.

Comment: so it allows you to redefine just some of the methods of an interface?

Comment: The important part is that `reverse` has a _member_ of type `Interface`.  This member then has its methods callable on the outer struct, or overrideable.

Comment: Could this feature (or approach) considered as a way to achieve what we do in Java thru. `extend` for extending non-abstract sub-classes? To me, this can be a handy way to override only certain methods while using the existing ones that are implemented by internal `Interface`.

Comment: So it's a kind of inheritance? And `return r.Interface.Less(j, i)` is calling the parent implementation?

Comment: Already the 2nd time I get confused about this. All the answers seem to forget the unintuitive usage of this struct (which is needed to actually sort anything): `sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(example)))`. For me the pain point here: the method Sort gets promoted to the reverse struct, but the call is non-member (receiver) style.

Answer (score 53):

Ok, the accepted answer helped me understand, but I decided to post an explanation which I think suits better my way of thinking.

The ["Effective Go"](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) has example of interfaces having embedded other interfaces:

```
// ReadWriter is the interface that combines the Reader and Writer interfaces.
type ReadWriter interface {
    Reader
    Writer
}
```

and a struct having embedded other structs:

```
// ReadWriter stores pointers to a Reader and a Writer.
// It implements io.ReadWriter.
type ReadWriter struct {
    *Reader  // *bufio.Reader
    *Writer  // *bufio.Writer
}
```

But there is no mention of a struct having embedded an interface. I was confused seeing this in `sort` package:

```
type Interface interface {
    Len() int
    Less(i, j int) bool
    Swap(i, j int)
}

...

type reverse struct {
    Interface
}
```

But the idea is simple. It's almost the same as:

```
type reverse struct {
    IntSlice  // IntSlice struct attaches the methods of Interface to []int, sorting in increasing order
}
```

methods of `IntSlice` being promoted to `reverse`.

And this:

```
type reverse struct {
    Interface
}
```

means that `sort.reverse` can embed any struct that implements interface `sort.Interface` and whatever methods that interface has, they will be promoted to `reverse`.

`sort.Interface` has method `Less(i, j int) bool` which now can be overridden:

```
// Less returns the opposite of the embedded implementation's Less method.
func (r reverse) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return r.Interface.Less(j, i)
}
```

---

My confusion in understanding

```
type reverse struct {
    Interface
}
```

was that I thought that a struct always has fixed structure, i.e. fixed number of fields of fixed types.

But the following proves me wrong:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// some interface
type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}

// a struct that implements Stringer interface
type Struct1 struct {
    field1 string
}

func (s Struct1) String() string {
    return s.field1
}


// another struct that implements Stringer interface, but has a different set of fields
type Struct2 struct {
    field1 []string
    dummy bool
}

func (s Struct2) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v, %v", s.field1, s.dummy)
}


// container that can embedd any struct which implements Stringer interface
type StringerContainer struct {
    Stringer
}


func main() {
    // the following prints: This is Struct1
    fmt.Println(StringerContainer{Struct1{"This is Struct1"}})
    // the following prints: [This is Struct1], true
    fmt.Println(StringerContainer{Struct2{[]string{"This", "is", "Struct1"}, true}})
    // the following does not compile:
    // cannot use "This is a type that does not implement Stringer" (type string)
    // as type Stringer in field value:
    // string does not implement Stringer (missing String method)
    fmt.Println(StringerContainer{"This is a type that does not implement Stringer"})
}
```

Comment: If my understanding is correct, interface values are represented by a a pointer to the instance assigned to it and a pointer to the method table of the type of the instance. So all interface values have the same structure in memory. Structurally, embedding is the same as composition. So even a struct embedding an interface would have a fixed structure. The structures of the instances the interface points to will be different.

Comment: I found this a better answer than the accepted one as it gave far more detail, a clear example and a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 30):

The statement

```
type reverse struct {
    Interface
}
```

enables you to initialize `reverse` with everything that implements the interface `Interface`. Example:

```
&reverse{sort.Intslice([]int{1,2,3})}
```

This way, all methods implemented by the embedded `Interface` value get populated to the outside while you are still able to override some of them in `reverse`, for example `Less` to reverse the sorting.

This is what actually happens when you use [`sort.Reverse`](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/sort/sort.go?name=go1.3#214). You can read about embedding [in the struct section of the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types).

Comment: Already the 2nd time I get confused about this. All the answers seem to forget the unintuitive usage of this struct (which is needed to actually sort anything): `sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(example)))`. For me the pain point here: the method Sort gets promoted to the reverse struct, but the call is non-member (receiver) style.

Comment: @seebi if this is a question I don't get it, sorry. Also the `Sort` method is not promoted, it takes something that satisfies `sort.Interface` and reverse is such a thing, it just changes the relevant methods of its embedded `sort.Interface` data so that the resulting sort is reversed.

Comment: not a question, just a remark, you're right I meant the Less, Swap, Len methods!

Answer (score 9):

I will give my explanation too. The `sort` package defines an unexported type `reverse`, which is a struct, that embeds `Interface`.

```
type reverse struct {
    // This embedded Interface permits Reverse to use the methods of
    // another Interface implementation.
    Interface
}
```

This permits Reverse to use the methods of another Interface implementation. This is the so called `composition`, which is a powerful feature of Go.

The `Less` method for `reverse` calls the `Less` method of the embedded `Interface` value, but with the indices flipped, reversing the order of the sort results.

```
// Less returns the opposite of the embedded implementation's Less method.
func (r reverse) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return r.Interface.Less(j, i)
}
```

`Len` and `Swap` the other two methods of `reverse`, are implicitly provided by the original `Interface` value because it is an embedded field. The exported `Reverse` function returns an instance of the `reverse` type that contains the original `Interface` value.

```
// Reverse returns the reverse order for data.
func Reverse(data Interface) Interface {
    return &reverse{data}
}
```

Comment: To me this looks like inheritance. "The `Less` method for `reverse` calls the `Less` method of the embedded `Interface` value, but with the indices flipped, reversing the order of the sort results." -- this looks like calling of the parent implementation.

Comment: For as long as type reverse has only one field that implements the Interface interface it also becomes a member of the Interface interface :0

Answer (score 6):

Embedding interfaces in a struct allows for partially "overriding" methods from the embedded interfaces. This, in turn, allows for delegation from the embedding struct to the embedded interface implementation.

The following example is taken from [this blog post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2020/embedding-in-go-part-3-interfaces-in-structs/).

Suppose we want to have a socket connection with some additional functionality, like counting the total number of bytes read from it. We can define the following struct:

```
type StatsConn struct {
  net.Conn

  BytesRead uint64
}
```

`StatsConn` now implements the `net.Conn` interface and can be used anywhere a `net.Conn` is expected. When a `StatsConn` is initialized with a proper value implementing `net.Conn` for the embedded field, it "inherits" all the methods of that value; the key insight is, though, that we can intercept any method we wish, leaving all the others intact. For our purpose in this example, we'd like to intercept the `Read` method and record the number of bytes read:

```
func (sc *StatsConn) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
  n, err := sc.Conn.Read(p)
  sc.BytesRead += uint64(n)
  return n, err
}
```

To users of `StatsConn`, this change is transparent; we can still call `Read` on it and it will do what we expect (due to delegating to `sc.Conn.Read`), but it will also do additional bookkeeping.

It's critical to initialize a `StatsConn` properly, otherwise the field retains its default value `nil` causing a `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`; for example:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", u.Host+":80")
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
sconn := &StatsConn{conn, 0}
```

Here `net.Dial` returns a value that implements `net.Conn`, so we can use that to initialize the embedded field of `StatsConn`.

We can now pass our `sconn` to any function that expects a `net.Conn` argument, e.g:

```
resp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(sconn)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
```

And later we can access its `BytesRead` field to get the total.

This is an example of wrapping an interface. We created a new type that implements an existing interface, but reused an embedded value to implement most of the functionality. We could implement this without embedding by having an explicit `conn` field like this:

```
type StatsConn struct {
  conn net.Conn

  BytesRead uint64
}
```

And then writing forwarding methods for each method in the `net.Conn` interface, e.g.:

```
func (sc *StatsConn) Close() error {
  return sc.conn.Close()
}
```

However, the `net.Conn` interface has many methods. Writing forwarding methods for all of them is tedious and unnecessary. Embedding the interface gives us all these forwarding methods for free, and we can override just the ones we need.

Answer (score 5):

I find this feature very helpful when writing **mocks** in **tests**.

Here is such an example:

```
package main_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

// Item represents the entity retrieved from the store
// It's not relevant in this example
type Item struct {
    First, Last string
}

// Store abstracts the DB store
type Store interface {
    Create(string, string) (*Item, error)
    GetByID(string) (*Item, error)
    Update(*Item) error
    HealthCheck() error
    Close() error
}

// this is a mock implementing Store interface
type storeMock struct {
    Store
    // healthy is false by default
    healthy bool
}

// HealthCheck is mocked function
func (s *storeMock) HealthCheck() error {
    if !s.healthy {
        return fmt.Errorf("mock error")
    }
    return nil
}

// IsHealthy is the tested function
func IsHealthy(s Store) bool {
    return s.HealthCheck() == nil
}

func TestIsHealthy(t *testing.T) {
    mock := &storeMock{}
    if IsHealthy(mock) {
        t.Errorf("IsHealthy should return false")
    }

    mock = &storeMock{healthy: true}
    if !IsHealthy(mock) {
        t.Errorf("IsHealthy should return true")
    }
}
```

By using:

```
type storeMock struct {
    Store
    ...
}
```

One doesn't need to mock all `Store` methods. Only `HealthCheck` can be mocked, since only this method is used in the `TestIsHealthy` test.

Below the result of the `test` command:

```
$ go test -run '^TestIsHealthy$' ./main_test.go           
ok      command-line-arguments  0.003s
```

A **real world example** of this use case one can find when testing the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/mocking-out-then-aws-sdk-for-go-for-unit-testing/).

---

To make it even more obvious, here is the ugly alternative - the minimum one needs to implement to satisfy the `Store` interface:

```
type storeMock struct {
    healthy bool
}

func (s *storeMock) Create(a, b string) (i *Item, err error) {
    return
}
func (s *storeMock) GetByID(a string) (i *Item, err error) {
    return
}
func (s *storeMock) Update(i *Item) (err error) {
    return
}

// HealthCheck is mocked function
func (s *storeMock) HealthCheck() error {
    if !s.healthy {
        return fmt.Errorf("mock error")
    }
    return nil
}

func (s *storeMock) Close() (err error) {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try another, low level approach to this.
Given the reverse struct:

```
type reverse struct {
    Interface
}
```

This beside others means, that reverse struct has a field `reverse.Interface`, and as a struct fields, it can be nil or have value of type Interface.
If it is not nil, then the fields from the Interface are promoted to the "root" = **reverse struct**. It might be eclipsed by fields defined directly on the reverse struct, but that is not our case.

When You do something like:
foo := reverse{}, you can println it via fmt.Printf("%+v", foo) and got

```
{Interface:<nil>}
```

When you do the

```
foo := reverse{someInterfaceInstance}
```

It is equivalent of:

```
foo := reverse{Interface: someInterfaceInstance}
```

It feels to me like You declare expectation, that implementation of **Interface** API should by injected into your struct **reverse** in runtime. And this api will be then promoted to the root of struct reverse.
At the same time, this still allow inconsistency, where You have reverse struct instance with reverse.Interface = < Nil>, You compile it and get the panic on runtime.

When we look back to the specifically example of the reverse in OP, I can see it as a pattern, how you can replace/extend behaviour of some instance / implementation kind of in runtime contrary to working with types more like in compile time when You do embedding of structs instead of interfaces.

Still, it confuses me a lot. Especially the state where the Interface is Nil :(.